# How to make such graph visualisation?

Tags: graphs

Having graph described in triples:
* vertex1 edge_type vertex2

Plus specification which color for which edge, vertex.

Feel free to choose any other format I can easily convert it to. My point is that I would like layouting to be as automatic as possible.

How to draw graph like below?

[image]

What I like is that edge_types are nicely written into edges making it most readable approach I've.

As bonus: adding extra layer on top, like above some nodes are circled and arrowed to others.

Comment: It's easy with `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-node`.

Comment: Will it do graph layouting when provided just relations?

Comment: I don't think so. You can define `\psobject`s that will the required shape, size and colour. As far as I know, the rest has to be doneby hand.